# Add objects to ArrayList In java

Tags: java

I have a class called "Product" having details of the products in a shop. This other class "Shop" is supposed to have methods. The product "a" is supposed to be saved in the ArrayList in the Shop class.I don't know why but every time I print List it returns [] with nothing inside. Why is that?
Product is made with the Instantse: Code, Quantity, and Price. I have the problem that they are different types of variables and I can't add them to the array.

```java
public class Shop {
    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
    static ArrayList<Object> List = new ArrayList<>();
    public static String nombre = "Shop";

    public Shop(String name) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }

    public Shop() {

    }

    public void addToList(Product a) {
        List.add(new Product());
    }

    public void searchProduct(String code) {

    }

    public void order(int min) {

    }
}
```

I print the List with

```java
System.out.println(Tienda.List);
```

The code for the Product class

```
public class Product {

Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
String Code;
int Quantity;
double Price;



public String getCode() {
    System.out.printf("Please introduce the code of the product");
    Code = sn.nextLine();
    return Code;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    System.out.println("Please introduce the quantity of the product");
    Quantity= sn.nextInt();
    return Quantity;
}

public double getPrice() {
    System.out.println("Please introduce the price for the product");
    Price= sn.nextInt();
    return Price;
}
```

Some of you asked for the main so here it is:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to"+ Tienda.name+" .What do you wanna do?\n1.Add new product\n2.Sell product");
        Product a = new Product();
        Shop shop = new Shop();
        switch(sn.nextInt()){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("You choose add a Product");
                a.getCode();
                a.getQuantity();
                a.getPice();
                tienda.addToList(a.Code);
                System.out.println("The code for the product is: "+a.Code+ "\nThe quantity of the product is: "+ a.Quantity+ " units"+ "\nThe price for the product is: "+ a.Price+ "$");
            case 2:




            default:
                System.out.printf("Wrong optin");
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that actually calls `addToList()` ?   Also, it's strange that `addToList()` ignores its argument and adds a new Product instead.

Comment: Please provide the code for product class.

Comment: @user16632363 It's perfectly fine to reference _static_ from _non-static_; it's the other way around that's the problem.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-  Duh, of course.  I'm not sure what I was thinking. I shall delete that comment to hide my shame.

Comment: @PranSukh there you go

Comment: There's nothing there that will cause it to not add it to a list, and I tested it myself that it gets added. How are you printing the list, and where?

Comment: @AnthonyCathers I posted the main as well hahaha.

Comment: You're not printing your list anywhere in that code?

Comment: @AnthonyCathers yes, I added it minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

If you make a `static ArrayList<Object> List = new ArrayList<>();` your objects will be stored. But all the properties of their identity as Product or Shop is lost. Instead create an `static ArrayList<Product> = new Arraylist<>()`.
Also there is no need to keep it static. The list will be referenced by each individual shop. I guess, it makes sense.